# Is there any way to detect file type and open it with GUI in terminal in Fedora?

Tags: command-line, file-opening

For example , there are two files `a.ppt` and `b.jpg` .

And I can call a magic method to open them appropriately just like :

```
magic_method a.ppt
magic_method b.jpg
```

And it open libreoffice writer and image viewer or something that fit the file type .

Is there any command or script for that?

Comment: For Mac users reading this, OS X has an `open` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open):

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http and https URLs.

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open) lists some alternative tools.